# c++ trying to use lower_bound with compare function on vector of tuple but error: no matching function for call to ‘get<0>(const std::tuple)’

Tags: c++, vector, tuples, c++14

I am trying to use lower_bound on a vector of the tuple. the compare function is trying to sort the first element in the tuple.
`

```
#include <iostream>     // std::court

#include <algorithm>    // std::lower_bound, std::upper_bound, std::sort
#include <vector>       // std::vector


static bool sortbysec(const std::tuple<double, double, double, double> &a,
                         const std::tuple<double, double, double, double> &b) {
    return (std::get<0>(a) < std::get<0>(b));
}
int main () {

 std::vector<std::tuple<double, double, double, double>> pieces;         // 10 20 30 30 20 10 10 20

pieces.push_back(std::make_tuple(10.0,22.2,30.3,227));
pieces.push_back(std::make_tuple(12.0,20.2,30.3,228));
pieces.push_back(std::make_tuple(228,20.2,30.3,228));
pieces.push_back(std::make_tuple(221,20.2,30.3,228));
std::vector<std::tuple<double, double, double, double>>::iterator up;
up = std::lower_bound(pieces.begin(), pieces.end(), std::make_tuple(max_end, -1, -1, -1), sortbysec);
        
std::cout << "lower_bound at position " << (low- v.begin()) << '\n';


return 0;
} `
```

error is like
/tmp/v4978P1vhB.cpp:8:26: error: no matching function for call to 'get<0>(const std::tuple<double, double, double, double>&)'
8 |     return (std::get<0>(a) < std::get<0>(b));
|                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/algorithm:60,
from /tmp/v4978P1vhB.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/utility:219:5: note: candidate: 'template<long unsigned int _Int, class _Tp1, class _Tp2> constexpr typename std::tuple_element<_Int, std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2> >::type& std::get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>&)'
219 |     get(std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>& __in) noexcept
|     ^~~
/usr/include/c++/9/utility:219:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/tmp/v4978P1vhB.cpp:8:26: note:   types 'std::pair<_Tp1, _Tp2>' and 'const std::tuple<double, double, double, double>' have incompatible cv-qualifiers
8 |     return (std::get<0>(a) < std::get<0>(b));

Comment: Once you manage to compile it, it is still wrong because `std::lower_bound()` requires a sorted range, and in your vector 228>221.

Comment: You are missing `#include <tuple>`. That should get the code to compile, but as noted earlier, it'd still be wrong.